# Moving/merging Team Sites

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, site, team-sites

We are trying to organize our Sharepoint sites because right now it is a mess off Team Sites with a lot of Site Pages underneath them.

Is it possible to move a full Team Site, with documents and everything, and add it to another Team Site as Site Page?

This so that in the end we have one "company" Team Site, with different departments underneath.

Any help or advise is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding Merge site pages**,

This operation should be achieved manually by

- Opening the site page library with explorer.

[image]

- Copy the required site pages from the source site to destination site.

**Regarding move a full Team Site**,

Yes , you can do this operation by executing `Export-SPWeb` and `Import-SPWeb` cmdlets, but some points need to check before do this.

- Make sure the destination site have the same language of the source site.
- Make sure the destination site have the same template of the source site (Team Site).
- Make sure the features that activated at source site is already activated at the destination site.

**To export site**

```
Export-SPWeb [-Identity] "site url or GUID" -Path "backup file path"
```

For Export-SPWeb details : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx

**To import the exported site**

```
Import-SPWeb [-Identity] "site url or GUID" -Path "backup file path"
```

For Import-SPWeb details: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx

**Note**: `Export-SPWeb` and `Import-SPWeb` operation will **overwrite** the destination site with source site.